# API showing up in console but not browser window

Tags: reactjs, api

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    persons: ''
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    axios.get(`https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=pokemon&utf8=&format=json`)
      .then(res => {
        const persons = res;
        this.setState({
          persons
        });
        console.log(this.state.persons.data.query.search[0].title);
      })
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>this.state.persons.data.query.search[0].title</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The console.log shows up fine but the p tag throws an error

Comment: axios.get('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=pokemon&origin=*&utf8=&format=json')
  .then(res => {
    const persons = res;
    this.setState({
      persons
    });
    console.log(this.state.persons.data.query.search[0].title);
  })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `state.persons` is empty on initializing, try verifying first:

```
render() {
   return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>{this.state.persons ? this.state.persons.data.query.search[0].title : null}</p>
      </div>
   );
}
```